# Using Jclouds without Maven

Tags: java, maven, jclouds

I want to use jclouds in my project.
But i saw that jclouds has some dependencies like (google inject, guava etc).

So, is there any easy way to using jclouds without using maven?

Answer (score 2):

The Guice and Guava dependencies are not Maven dependencies, but jclouds dependencies. Maven is just a build tool, and regardless of the tool of your choice (Maven, Gradle, javac), jclouds needs those dependencies to work.

If you just want to get jclouds and all the jars you need to get it working, you can follow the [install guide](http://jclouds.apache.org/start/install/). The last section there shows you how to easily fetch all dependencies to a directory in your filesystem.